# In PHP, can you access a parent object from an object from which it is composed?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a base class of FileCopier that is composed with two "has-a" associations to Resource Source and Resource Destination.

After construction, three properties exist in FileCopier:

```
- Source (instance of Resource)
- Destination (instance of Resource)
- Config (array of configuration stuff for this FileCopier)
```

All of the examples I find on this issue are regarding children by extension rather than children by composition.

My question is: is there any way for the Resource instance to access it's parent's "Config"?

Or, must I pass a reference to the parent to it's associated children, say, via the constructor?

Comment: You have a simple assosiation between FileCopier and Resource, and that association by your definition goes one way only (from FileCopier to Resource), so I would say that the answer to your question is: no, you can't magically access FileCopier from Resource unless you specifically pass the reference.

Comment: not sure if this is what you are getting at but parent::attributeName

Comment: @The_asMan parent would work if Resource inherited from FileCopier, but according to his description, FileCopier has 2 attributes of class Resource... so parent would not work, would it?

Comment: He just wants to access the Config array so yes it should work. FileCopier is the parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you have:

```
class FileCopier{
    /* @var Source */
    private $source;

    /* @var Destination */
    private $destination;

    /* @var Config */
    private $conf;

    ...

}
```

And you want to access $conf from $source and $destination?
There is no parent or other magic word to access this $conf from the two other variables.
Your best bet would be to add a function to Resource which will set a local reference to Config:

```
class Resource {
    /* @var Config */
    protected $config;
    ...
    function setConfig(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or if config is set at some other point r could change or if for whatever other reason you want to access the latest $conf from your resources you can pass a ref to FileCopier instead:

```
class Resource {
    /* @var FileCopier */
    protected $copier;
    ...
    function setFileCopier(FileCopier $copier) {
        $this->copier = $copier;
        // and access to $this->copier->conf through a getter
        // or make $conf public in FileCopier
    }
    ...
}
```

Then all you have to do is to call your setter before using $source and $destination. Probably in the FileCopier:

```
class FileCopier{
    ...
    //first case :
    function setConfig($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->source->setConfig($config);
        $this->destination->setConfig($config);
    }

    // Or for the second case:
    function setup() {
        $this->source = new Source();
        $this->source->setFileCopier($this);

        $this->destination = new Destination();
        $this->destination->setFileCopier($this);
    }

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Coyote, thanks!  I didn't even classify Config but, why not.  I think associating an instance of Config at FileCopier->Config and then passing a reference to this instance would be a good one.  I had thought of passing the FileCopier instance itself and providing public access to the config but I think the Config reference itself would be more clear as (in PHP at least) it provides me with a way to more specifically type hint the argument (rather than just using Array, etc).  Nice.

Comment: Hi! Happy to help. You don't have to classify it you can just use explicit references for built-in types. Something like function setConfig(&$config) should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the responsibilities of your objects.

If both Resources are created by the FileCopier object, you could supply the config from the FileCopier through the constructor of the Resource class (if all resources should have a configuration - otherwise through a property/getter&setter).

If the FileCopier is the thing that is configured, and Resources will know about the FileCopier it is currently being used in (either through the constructor or a property), then the FileCopier should just have a getConfig() or use ->config if the property is public.

From your naming I'm having a bit of trouble of seeing the actual use case where a resource must know the configuration of the object performing any work on the resource itself. It might be more better to move that part of configuration (i.e. if it's a "save" or "move" command on the resource) to the actual method call (and call ->save() where the FileCopier object uses the path from its configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  Resource has a URI object, a TempFile, and an Adapter the latter of which interfaces ProtocolAdapter so I can drop in support for various protocols represented in the "scheme" of the URI.  My biggest problem is sharing the config with the children that need it.  I think I'm going to take halfer's advice and pass the config to Resource's constructor.  "Configuration" is where I have the biggest problem with coupling.  Judging by questions posted by many OOP programmers I can see I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, "parent" is the wrong term, though I know what you mean. If an object F is an instanceof FileCopier, and has two properties that are both instanceof Resource, then the object F is not the parent of the resource instances. Not quite sure what one does call that relationship, tbh :-o

You can permit the resource instances access to your config though. Do something like this in your FileCopier class:

```
public function setSource(Resource $r)
{
    $this->Source = $r;
    $r->setConfig($this->Config);
}
```

That way the resource can be 'notified' of the config transparently.

Comment: halfer, thanks.  I believe the relationship is commonly referred to as "Association" or "has-a".  I have a design pattern book that advises to favor "composition" over inheritance.  Objects are composed with associations and extended with inheritance.  I hope I'm write about that ;)

Comment: No problem. Yes, in your use-case, inheritance doesn't feel right. In my view one gets to learn this the hard way by having used such an approach in the past, and then finding that the class needs to inherit from two parents!